# RVM. getting git-related error while installing ruby

Tags: git, rvm

I'm using RVM and want to install another version of Ruby.

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2-head
/Users/ovsiiko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-head - #fetching 
error: You have local changes to 'win32/configure.bat'; cannot switch branches.
From https://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_2 -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to 'win32/configure.bat' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
There has been an error while checking out branch ruby_1_9_2.           
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Spotlight doesn't see neither `win32` folders nor `configure.bat` files.
Actualy I don't get which folder this error message refers. 
Already had `git stash` in all my recent git based projects and keep getting the same.

Any ideas how to fix this??

Thank you

P.S. I'm using MacOS X 10.6.4

UPDATE:
I've uninstalled RVM then reinstalled it and tried again...

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2-head
/Users/ovsiiko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-head - #fetching 
Cloning from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ovsiiko/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 30907, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14057/14057), done.
remote: Total 30907 (delta 23362), reused 22680 (delta 16110)
Receiving objects: 100% (30907/30907), 21.45 MiB | 261 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23362/23362), done.
Checking out files: 100% (3515/3515), done.
error: You have local changes to 'symbian/configure.bat'; cannot switch branches.
From https://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_2 -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to 'symbian/configure.bat' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
There has been an error while checking out branch ruby_1_9_2.           
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Now this attempt returned error at `symbian/configure.bat`.

Could it be virus?

Comment: Just a tip: the fact that Spotlight doesn't find a file in no way means it doesn't exist. Spotlight doesn't index the whole filesystem. For a more complete search, use [find](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Looks like there is some mess with RVM, did this command to fix it.

```
$ rvm cleanup repos
```

Answer (score 0):

The git repo that rvm is complaining about is, quite obviously, one of those found under `~/.rvm`, and specifically, the `ruby-1.9.2-head` repo.

Go to `~/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head`, stash your changes and you should be fine.

Comment: thank you for the hint. what rvm command I should use to install -head version after git stash in ~/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head ? 'rvm install 1.9.2-head' returns the same error again ... thank you

Comment: weird. what was the output of `git stash`? was anything saved in the stash?

Comment: warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in test/rexml/data/t63-2.svg.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in test/rexml/data/testsrc.xml.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in test/rexml/data/ticket_61.xml.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in win32/configure.bat.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in win32/ifchange.bat.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in win32/rm.bat.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in win32/rmall.bat.
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in win32/rmdirs.bat.
Saved working directory and index state WIP on trunk: 5a17f4c fix spaces.

Comment: HEAD is now at 5a17f4c fix spaces.